# Select Dropdown doesn´t update inside flat list

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to have a select dropdown inside the flatlist to be scrollable as the data inside, so i put my select dropdown inside the ListHeaderComponent method of flatlist. When i click on item of select dropdown  the text box doesn´t update. I will put my code in here

```
const getCardTotal = () => {
        return <View><SelectDropdown
            buttonTextStyle={{ color: "white" }}
            rowTextStyle={{ color: "black" }}
            dropdownStyle={styles.dropd}
            buttonStyle={styles.drop}
            data={filtragem}
            onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
                setSelecionadoCampo1(selectedItem)
            }}
            buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
                // text represented after item is selected
                // if data array is an array of objects then return selectedItem.property to render after item is selected
                return campo_selecionado
            }}
            rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => {
                // text represented for each item in dropdown
                // if data array is an array of objects then return item.property to represent item in dropdown
                return item
            }}
        />
}
```

Then i call this on flatlist

```
<FlatList
    data={vendas}
    ListHeaderComponent={getCardTotal}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
/>
```